# Is it possible to use the default graph from neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, data-visualization, javascript

I'm using neo4j for a web-app I am creating. I have no problem getting data back from the REST API as I expect. However, I would prefer to not have to deal with lots of custom work in terms of graphing everything. I would love to just be able to embed/use the same graph that neo4j uses to show you query results at `http://localhost:7474/browser/` on my page. I tried doing an iFrame to it but that had all sorts of problems.

Is this possible? I've been looking for an hour now trying to figure out how to do it or what libraries they use, but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check out my demo project, which uses two visualizations (two branches) one which is very close to what Neo4j Server uses (all js client code talking to a Neo4j server):

demo:

http://jexp.github.io/cy2neo/

branch master:

https://github.com/jexp/cy2neo

branch neo3d:

https://github.com/jexp/cy2neo/tree/neod3

Comment: Is it possible to dynamically set the query text without typing it in? I'm hoping to set it via an NLP program I'm running. Say, via a document.getElementById('#cypher').val = "my new query". It's strange. This seems to change the dom element without changing what is actually displayed.

Comment: That's because of codemirror (the highlighting) there should be an API function in codemirror to update the text but I don't know it out of my head.